# Accessing a sibling value inside of a property list

Tags: javascript

So here's my code:

```
var room = {
    foo: [0, 1, 0, 0],
    bar: {0: true, 1: false},
    layers: [[this.foo, this.bar], [this.foo, this.bar]],
};
```

I'm creating a map data structure for a simple canvas game. The problem is my layers property comes up as `undefined` for each element. How can I access foo and bar inside of layers properly to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = [0, 1, 0, 0];
var bar = {0: true, 1:false};
var room = {
    foo:foo,
    bar:bar,
    layers:[[foo, bar], [foo, bar]]
};
```

Edit after comment:
I don't know that you will be able to do this without defining the inputs outside of the object literal, or not using object literal notation.  Here is a working version without defining room using object literal notation:

```
function Room(){
        this.foo = [0,1,0,0];
        this.bar = {0:true, 1:false};
        this.layers =  [[this.foo, this.bar], [this.foo,this.bar]];
}
    var room = new Room();
    alert("result:"+room.layers[0][0]);
```

Comment: This will work, but is there a way I can access foo and bar directly as siblings?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a getter:

```
var room = {
    foo: [0, 1, 0, 0],
    bar: {0: true, 1: false},
    get layers (){ return [[this.foo, this.bar], [this.foo, this.bar]]}
};
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLNEj/